# How does balance of nodes calculated in Ethereum network?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, wallets, balances

As a beginner of the topic, I am trying to understand the storage concept in Ethereum and smart contracts. Each of the network nodes has a public address called a digital wallet for managing the assets.  During a consensus cycle, one node may call the transfer function of the smart contract so that some amount from its balance will be transferred to the given address, if smart contract approves the sender has enough balance.

Here, I know that `balance` is a variable "stored" in a smart contract, although it is calculated by checking the updates made to this `balance` through first to last block. Because a change made to the smart contract variable is a transaction of  **`balance` is 10 now**. So rather than storing a variable somewhere, it is learned by checking these kinds of transactions.

Today, while reading an article, I saw this: "*The changes will be made on new unspent transactions. Ethereum, Stellar, EOS and RSK adopt account-
based model, in which the balance of an address is
recorded directly instead of calculating all the unspent
transaction amounts*"

This seems to contradict my whole understanding of storage concept in a smart contract of Ethereum, since they stated the balance of an address is recorded directly. But to my knowledge, it is not recorded but rather calculated after any node queries about balance to the smart contract. I will be very happy to get feedback about my understanding of the concept.

Comment: In the account model the balances are maintained in the database like structure and in utxo model the balances result from adding up the utxo for the account. Ethereum doesn't have the concept of unspent transaction. If you have more doubts please create a new question.